# Repair an ceramic sink / enamel, and have perfect color match

Tags: painting, paint, ceramic-tile

There was a little hole in this ceramic sink:

[image]

and I filled it with this ["GEB Enamel Repair Paste"](http://www.geb.fr/en/fiche.php?n=1.6.28.89.211). It works very well by mixing the resin and the hardener.

After 24 hours, I finished the work with sandpaper (with smaller and smaller grain).

The result is very good when you touch it (you cannot really feel the difference), the picture here is *after* the repair.

**The only problem is the color**: the sink is white, but not so pure white than the resin.

**I know it's probably not worth it because the sink could be replaced for cheap** (and it's old anyway), **but I take it as a challenge** to learn new techniques: would there be techniques to have a perfect repair in terms of color?

Are there some enamel paint that I could buy, with different shades of white?

I know it's possible: I saw a Youtube video in which a dental technician used many ceramic paints to match perfect color with dental prosthesis.

Answer (score 4):

I am very dubious of the possibility of "a **perfect** repair in terms of color". Perhaps you should be simply asking "How could I tint this epoxy repair paste?".

You can use regular paint pigments to tint 2-part epoxies. Using a flat board as a pallette, stir up some dabs of paste and start adding small amounts of various pigments to each dab. When cured, compare each dab to the surface to be repaired until a close match is found. Keep careful track of dab size and pigment used so you can duplicate for the actual repair.

This is an art, not a science. You might get close right away, or you might go through 20 "test" packages of epoxy and 100 (1000?) dabs of paste before you get it right.

Comment: mix up the eamples but then divide each sample in half but only add the hardener to half of the sample.  when the match is found use the other half of the sample to do the repair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just two little additional questions: 1) what kind of tint would you use (would you have just a link, not for shipping purpose, but just to know what kind of tint you're speaking about)

Comment: 2) Would the tint be added to the resin *during* the mix of the 2 parts, i.e. it will be a mix: resin+hardener+tint (it seems to be what you say in you answer)?... Or would the tint be applied, as a paint, when the resin-mix is *dry*? The latter seems to be what I saw in the Youtube video of a dental technician making prosthesis and painting them after. See also https://www.cosmedent.com/shop-by-department/opaques-and-tints/products/creative-color-tints/ (I don't say I should buy this, not at all, but just something that seems to confirm it can be painted after...) I'm not sure...

Comment: Painting after will probably not work. Those dental treatments are high-tech UV cured polymers and not used as stand-alone "paint"; they require pre and post application of other specialty products, very expensive. *You* should add standard paint pigment to the resin then add hardener. To be honest, the whole scenario seems impractical and improbable, just paint the whole sink with epoxy, no?